# How to fix function scope issues when calling a function

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, scope

I'm studying a project by Wes Bos where you were tasked with adding shift click functionality to a series of list items.

I completed this and wanted to go further by then adding the ability to deselect these list items which I did (see commented javascript code).

Then I wanted to take that solution and apply DRY principles and that's where things became difficult.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Hold Shift to Check Multiple Checkboxes</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            html {
              font-family: sans-serif;
              background: #ffc600;
            }
            .inbox {
              max-width: 400px;
              margin: 50px auto;
              background: white;
              border-radius: 5px;
              box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
            }
            .item {
              display: flex;
              align-items: center;
              border-bottom: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
            }
            .item:last-child {
              border-bottom: 0;
            }
            input:checked + p {
              background: #F9F9F9;
              text-decoration: line-through;
            }
            input[type="checkbox"] {
              margin: 20px;
            }
            input:hover {
              cursor: pointer;
            }
            p {
              margin: 0;
              padding: 20px;
              transition: background 0.2s;
              flex: 1;
              font-family:'helvetica neue';
              font-size: 20px;
              font-weight: 200;
              border-left: 1px solid #D1E2FF;
            }
        </style>
        <!--
        The following is a common layout you would see in an email client.

        When a user clicks a checkbox, holds Shift, and then clicks another checkbox a few rows down, all the checkboxes inbetween those two checkboxes should be checked.

        -->
        <div class="inbox">
            <div class="item">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <p>This is an inbox layout.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <p>Check one item</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <p>Hold down your Shift key</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <p>Check a lower item</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <p>Everything in between should also be set to checked</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <p>Try to do it without any libraries</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <p>Just regular JavaScript</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <p>Good Luck!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <p>Don't forget to tweet your result!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            const input = document.querySelectorAll('.item input[type="checkbox"]');
            let lastchecked; 

            function checkFunction (event) {
                let inbetween = false;
                if (event.shiftKey && this.checked) {
                    tickBox(true);
                } else if (event.shiftKey && !this.checked) {
                    tickBox(false);
                }
                lastChecked = this;
            }

            function tickBox(boolean) {
                input.forEach(box => { 
                    if (box === this || box === lastChecked) {
                        inbetween = !inbetween;
                    }
                    if (inbetween) {
                        box.checked = boolean;
                    }
                });
            }

            input.forEach(box => box.addEventListener('click', checkFunction));


        //    const input = document.querySelectorAll('.item input[type="checkbox"]');
        //    let lastchecked; 
        //    
        //    function checkFunction (event) {
        //        let inbetween = false;
        //        if (event.shiftKey && this.checked) {
        //            input.forEach(box => {  
        //                if (box === this || box === lastChecked) {
        //                    inbetween = !inbetween;
        //                }
        //                if (inbetween) {
        //                    box.checked = true;
        //                }
        //            });
        //        } else if (event.shiftKey && !this.checked) {
        //            input.forEach(box => {  
        //                if (box === this || box === lastChecked) {
        //                    inbetween = !inbetween;
        //                }
        //                if (inbetween) {
        //                    box.checked = false;
        //                }
        //            });
        //        }
        //        lastChecked = this;
        //    }
        //    
        //    input.forEach(box => box.addEventListener('click', checkFunction));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expected at that point that all I had to do was call the function where the code was repeated, but this time using a boolean parameter, however it then says that the inbetween variable is undefined. I'm confused at this point. If I define it within the new function it just ticks everything and doesn't change the variable back to false etc.

I hope that makes sense. I'd love to know where I'm going wrong for the future.

Thanks all.

Comment: Function scopes are private.  Nothing outside the scope can reach variables inside the scope.  Your `inbetween` variable will have to be stored somewhere outside the function scope if you want to reach it from outside that function.  If you can describe what the purpose is of that `inbetween` variable, I might be able to offer a different idea.

Comment: FYI, you might also just be able to pass `inbetween` to `tickBox()` as an argument and return any new value.  Since `tickBox()` appears to only be called from within `checkFunction()`, that could work.

Comment: Or, you could define `tickBox()` within `checkFunction()` so it can see the `checkFunction()` scope.  Functions can be declared inside other functions and then they share access to the parent's scope.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00 basically the inbetween variable is there to determine whether or not a box is between the previous and currently ticked boxes. It evaluates to true if the box is equal to the current box ticked/ last box ticked and then changes back to false when it reaches the other side. I'll try the suggestions you've offered. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest declaring `tickBox()` inside of `checkFunction()`.  This is feasible because it's never called elsewhere.  Then, it can have access to the scope of `checkFunction()` including the `inbetween` variable:

```
const input = document.querySelectorAll('.item input[type="checkbox"]');
let lastchecked; 

function checkFunction (event) {
    let inbetween = false;

    function tickBox(boolean) {
        input.forEach(box => { 
            if (box === this || box === lastChecked) {
                inbetween = !inbetween;
            }
            if (inbetween) {
                box.checked = boolean;
            }
        });
    }

    if (event.shiftKey && this.checked) {
        tickBox(true);
    } else if (event.shiftKey && !this.checked) {
        tickBox(false);
    }
    lastChecked = this;
}

input.forEach(box => box.addEventListener('click', checkFunction));
```

---

FYI, you  can simplify your i`f/else` from this:

```
    if (event.shiftKey && this.checked) {
        tickBox(true);
    } else if (event.shiftKey && !this.checked) {
        tickBox(false);
    }
```

to this:

```
    if (event.shiftKey) {
        tickBox(this.checked);
    }
```

Which then means that you don't actually need a separate function for `tickBox()` any more.